# spring data jpa can't use native sql to update data

Tags: spring, jpa

I try insert，delte,update method . My code:

```java
package com.example.tx.repository;

import com.example.tx.entity.Blog;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public interface BlogRepository extends CrudRepository<Blog,Long> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "insert into blog (title,content) value(:title,:content)",nativeQuery = true)
    void saveBlog(@Param("title") String title,@Param("content") String content);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying 
    @Query(value = "update  blog   set  content = :content where id = :id" ,nativeQuery = true)
    void update(@Param("id") Long id,@Param("content") String content);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "delete from blog where id = :id",nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteWithId(@Param("id") Long id );
}
```

idea log

```
2020-04-29 14:50:26,110 restartedMain DEBUG AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=UNCACHED (user specified null, default is UNCACHED)
2020-04-29 14:50:26,110 restartedMain DEBUG org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock does not support precise timestamps.
14:50:26.112 [restartedMain] DEBUG com.example.tx.TxApplication - Running with Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.5.RELEASE
14:50:26.112 [restartedMain] INFO  com.example.tx.TxApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
14:50:30.050 [restartedMain] INFO  com.example.tx.TxApplication - Started TxApplication in 4.269 seconds (JVM running for 6.579)
Hibernate: update  blog   set  content = ? where id = ?
```

only the update method can't work , the data can't change, how to resolve it ?

Comment: What do you mean the data can't change? Are you getting an error?

Comment: no, no error , database data can't change ,Persistence failed。

Comment: Meaning you get no error upon calling `update` and the row simply does not change?

Comment: if this is  not a typo.. the insert should not work too.... `value` instead of `values`

Comment: So I was very confused。

Comment: did you see some "generated" sql in logs ?

Comment: just one : update blog  set content = ? where id = ?

Comment: when I check you interface content I wonder why you resolve all your use-case with native queries.... why don't use spring data for what he does best ?

Comment: I think it would be better to use native SQL if only one field was updated, so I tried to do this

Comment: could you improve your question by adding some logs, database content, before/after values...

Comment: https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-log-sql-statements-and-their-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

```
you've to put below properties in @Modifying annotation like blow,
 @Transactional
   @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true,flushAutomatically = true)
    @Query(value = "update  blog   set  content = :content where id = :id" ,nativeQuery = true)
    void update(@Param("id") Long id,@Param("content") String content);
```